# How to display multiple multi-value fields inside one for loop?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

Here is what I've come up with but it seems I can't do [key] to increment along with the body for loop...

```
 {% for key, item in content.body if key|first != '#' %}

{{ item }}

  {{ content.field_text.[key] }}

   {{ content.field_image.[key] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What template file name are you using?

Comment: If you are rendering fields, why not just `{{ content.field_name }}`? Could you explain what you are attempting to do?

Comment: This is inside a custom block. Each field can have unlimited values, and I need to add divs and structure to each set.   So I am looping through content.body and also need to display the correct version of the other fields at the same time.  content.field_text.0 for the first loop, content.field_text.1 for the 2nd, and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use square brackets `[]` in twig, you don't need a period `.`

```
{% for key, item in content.body if key|first != '#' %}

  {{ item }}

  {{ content.field_text[key] }}

  {{ content.field_image[key] }}

{% endfor %}
```

---

A better solution for this might be a field collection or a paragraph, because you depend on that the user is keeping the deltas of the fields in sync.

Comment: Without the period it is calling the array, not the next one in order. So content.field_text.0, content.field_text.1, content.field_text.2 is not called in order of loop.   I will look into the Paragraph module but really dislike adding more modules if it can be done in twig.

Comment: I think the point of your code is to get the same delta from all three fields to group them in a div. The next one in order you get on the next round of the loop. As mentioned this only works if all three fields have the same deltas. Did you check this? The body has by default only one value.

Comment: `
{% for key, item in content.field_body_unlimited if key|first != '#' %}
   {% if key < "1" %}
    <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id='panel{{ key }}'>
  {% else %}
    <div class="tabs-panel" id='panel{{ key }}'>
  {% endif %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        {{ content.field_image_unlimited[key] }}
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        {{ item }}
        <BR><BR>
        {{ content.field_entity_link_unlimited[key] }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
`

Comment: Not sure why it isn't formatting as code above, but that is what I have.  What is happening is all but the first loop is printing the 6th image.

Comment: I got it working by using a separate variable [i], instead of the key.  {% set i = i + 1 %}

Comment: Good, but trying to theme this all in one node template, you get horrible code and not easy to debug. If you would structure your data with Field Collection or Paragraphs you get also nicely structured twig files. And the layout you design is reusable.